# Is PHP preg_replace with '[\W]' or '[\D]' sufficient sanitization for $_get vars?

Tags: php, mysql, get, icalendar, sanitization

I have an ical script that accepts a few different $_GET vars, performs a MYSQL SELECT query, and spits out an .ical file.

The $_GET vars are either integers or Alpha and valid requests will never contain special chars. The values are all pre-defined (by me) - the alpha var is simply a two letter location code parameter from existing data in the database. Again ONLY SELECT queries will ever be performed with the data.  I know there are many methods of sanitization with PHP, but currently, this is what I'm using.

```
$foo = preg_replace('[\D]', '', $_GET["foo"]); // only accept numeric chars
$bar = preg_replace('[\W]', '', $_GET["bar"]); // only accept alpha chars
```

It simply replaces any non-numeric or non-alpha chars with an empty space, thus (I think) removing the threat of injection attacks.

It seems like a really simple, low overhead approach compared to other options, but are there any *security* risks with this approach?

Comment: Besides being extremely limiting (prevents people with names like `James O'Bannon` or `Rodrigo de la Fuente` or `René Artois` from registering, it's not a good solution.... the recommended solution is prepared statements with bind variables, though it's certainly sensible to validate numeric inputs as well

Comment: Rather than trying to make bad data good, just reject it.  Why take some hacker's attempt and remove dangerous stuff and insert into your database? This applies to data that you have already defined should ONLY be alpha or ONLY be digits.

Comment: "valid requests will never contain special chars" I have a hyphenated last name and am regularly told my last name is "invalid". We're good at making bad assumptions. Read http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ for example.

Comment: I use [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) which is probably doing something similar in the background. There's lots of [filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php) that you can use as well.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. @MarkBaker In this case, all of the values are known IDs in the database. The alpha value `should` only be a known location code of the form XX. I've edited the Question for clarity.

Comment: @AbraCadaver The data is only used in the where clause of a SELECT statement to return data about one or more calendar events. So assuming they can't inject an INSERT or UPDATE statement into the data, nothing gets written to the database. That is the nature of my question though. Does this in-fact prevent SQL (or other) injection? Does it have other _security_ risks?

Comment: Why don't you simply get in the habit of always using prepared statements/bind variables.... then you don't have to use different approaches to handling queries depending on what you're doing, which simplifies your code